# How can I figure out which line of my routes.rb file has Rails 2 grammar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've converted my (pretty large) routes.rb file to Rails 3 style, but I'm still getting deprecation warnings. I suspect there is some option or flag in there that I missed, but I don't know where it is.

Is there a trick I can do to figure out where it's coming from? I suppose I could iteratively comment out blocks of it and then run the checker on it… ugh.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than it being your own `config/routes.rb` file, it could be one provided by a gem such as declarative_authorization or ckeditor. Check the gems you're using on the project if they contain a `config/routes.rb` file.

If none of them contain one, then please show us your `config/routes.rb`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Rails Upgrade](https://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade) plugin to check for outdated syntax

Comment: Does that tell me which line? (too lazy to check…)

Comment: @John Anything flagged by the plugin should give you file & line number.

Comment: I just ran it-- no file numbers. Also it doesn't detect an old routes file, but the deprecation warnings still show up in my tests. guess i'll just have to dig in the rails code.

Comment: @John you should post your routes file, at this point we're just guessing.